# Container-bound Apps Script does not execute properly from change to Google Sheet under certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms, execution

I have a container-bound script that reads data from a Google Sheet (its container), creates an event in a Google Calendar and then updates the Google Sheet with a confirmation to say that it has created a calendar event. The script is triggered to execute every time there is a **change** to the spreadsheet.

During testing, the script works perfectly as it should. However, when data is automatically entered into the Google Sheet from a Google Form (followed by some changes made through a Google Forms add-on), the script executes but **does not update the Sheet** with the confirmation of a new calendar event. This then results in the script creating duplicate calendar events because it does not see the confirmation in the Google Sheet.

Here is an excerpt of my Google Sheet data:
[Google Sheet data for employee leave details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7B5l.jpg)

And below is my script:

```
function synctocalendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("Calendar_sync!H2").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var submissions = spreadsheet.getRange("Calendar_sync!A2:F").getValues();

  var last = submissions.length-1 

  for (x=last; x>0; x--) {

    var shift = submissions[x];
    var startTime = shift[2];
    var endTime = shift[3];
    var title = shift[0]+" | "+shift[1];
    var ssr = x+2
    
    if (shift[4]!=="" && shift[4]!=="Complete" && shift[4]!=="Declined" && shift[4]!=="In progress") {
      break

    } else if (shift[4]=="Complete" && shift[5]!=="Y" && shift[5]!=="N") {
      eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
      var endf = spreadsheet.getRange(ssr,6)
      endf.setValue("Y")
      break
      
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the script directly from the editor it works perfectly. It reads the data, creates a calendar event, then returns a "Y" in column F (provided it satisfies the IF criteria).

When I have a trigger set to run the script whenever a change is made to the sheet, I can again get the script to run as I expect by manually deleting the "Y" from column F in any one of the rows.

However, when a new submission is written to the Google Sheet from a Google Form (followed by some spreadsheet changes made from a Google Forms add-on for approvals), the script still runs and still creates a calendar event, but does not write a "Y" back into the sheet.

**EDIT:** Details on the Google Forms add-on

The add-on sends emails on form submission with the form data to be approved. Once the recipient of the email approves the data from the Google Form, the add-on makes changes to the spreadsheet to reflect that.
i.e. when a form is submitted, column E in the spreadsheet will say "In Progress" and once the approval process is complete, the add-on will change column E to say "Complete". At this point, the script recognises it is complete and creates a calendar event.

Comment: From `when data is automatically entered into the Google Sheet from a Google Form, the script executes but does not update the Sheet with the confirmation of a new calendar event.`, I guessed that in your situation, `synctocalendar()` might be installed as the installable OnSubmit trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not sure I understand your statement but the synctocalendar() function is triggered by any change to the Sheet that the script is bound to. That is the only direct trigger for that function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `the synctocalendar() function is triggered by any change to the Sheet that the script is bound to. That is the only direct trigger for that function.`, I understood that you might use the installable OnEdit or OnChange trigger. If my understanding is correct, in this case, please use the OnSubmit trigger. By this, when Google Form is submitted, the script works. By the way, in your actual situation, the sheet of "Calendar_sync" is the 1st tab? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Whenever is possible add data as text instead of image.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for clarifying. Yes your understanding is correct. I can change it to an onsubmit trigger, but this probably won't be suitable for my sheet. I should have mentioned about the approval process that occurs post-formsubmit but pre calendar event creation from a Google Form add-on I am using. I have now added this to the original post.

Comment: Also, it is not the first tab in the sheet, but I have tried that; also without success.

Comment: "followed by some changes made through a Google Forms add-on" it's unclear what you mean. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @AN_DOP Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details.